# How do I convert python JSON into a html table in Flask server?

Tags: python, html, json, flask, raspberry-pi

I have installed flask in raspberry pi.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello world'

@app.route('/detect')
def detect():
    labels = os.popen('python3 detect.py').read()
    return jsonify(labels)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8000, host='0.0.0.0')
```

in the detect() method i have converted the labels into JSON. It is of the format {"John":"Yes","David":"No"} format. But I need to convert this JSON into a HTML table and render it as a html template.
so that it looks like

```
Name  Status
John  Yes
David No
```

How do I achieve it?? 
I have seen lot of questions in StackOverflow but I don't get any correct solution for my question.

Comment: You should use html template. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/

Comment: `{% for name, status in data.items %}<tr><td>{{ name }}</td><td>{{ status }}</td></tr>{% endfor %}` where you supply this dictionary with the name `data` to your template.

Comment: use render_template to render a html passing in the labels as data: `return render_template('template.html', labels=labels)` not sure if you should jsonify if it comes in as a list then you should be fine using that in jinja2 temaplate -- Flask [quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/) is really helpful recommend going through that

Comment: @sytech I have edited like this `return render_template('template.html' , data = labels)` but it doesn't show any html table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First import `render_template_string` from flask by adding `from flask import render_template_string` in the script

then in the route instead of `return jsonify(labels)` replace with the below,

```
return render_template_string('''


    <table>
            <tr>
                <td> Name </td> 
                <td> Status </td>
            </tr>


    {% for name, status in labels.items() %}

            <tr>
                <td>{{ name }}</td> 
                <td>{{ status }}</td>
            </tr>

    {% endfor %}


    </table>
''', labels=labels)
```

I hope this helps.